# Accessing D drive from the ubuntu VM installed in windows 11 pro OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a windows 11 pro OS installed on my system. It is installed on my C drive, which is a 512 GB M.2. In the C drive, I have installed Oracle VM VirtualBox manager and then created a Ubuntu 20.02 version VM. Now there is another 1 TB HDD which is the D drive in my system. All my working files are kept there. How can I access my D drive from the ubuntu OS installed in my VM? I cannot find a suitable and clear step-by-step solution over the internet. I am new to the use of VM, and therefore, any help will be appreciated.

PS: I don't want to partition my 512 GB M.2 and install ubuntu there.

Answer (score 1):

In your VirtualBox, select your VM then go Settings>Shared Folders. Click on Add new shared folder (+ Icon) and proceed to choose Drive D.Check on Automount option if you want the drive to be visible every time you boot your VM.  [image]

[image]